# How to run Profile Report from pandas_profiling?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-profiling

I imported pandas, numpy and pandas profiling with codes below but for some reason it won't display any data but 3 lines of information, so here are codes:

```
from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport
profile=ProfileReport(df, title='Pandas Profiling Report', html={'style':{'full_width':True}})
profile
```

...and here is the output:

```
HBox(children=(HTML(value='Summarize dataset'), FloatProgress(value=0.0, max=26.0), HTML(value='')))


HBox(children=(HTML(value='Generate report structure'), FloatProgress(value=0.0, max=1.0), HTML(value='')))


HBox(children=(HTML(value='Render HTML'), FloatProgress(value=0.0, max=1.0), HTML(value='')))
```

Does anyone have an idea why it doesn't work, please?

Comment: If using Jupyter, you can try enabling widgets. Type the following in the console then restart Jupyter and run the report again. `jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension` [Instructions in the docs](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html)

Comment: I'm already using Jupyter on Internet Explorer. Also I tried extension code from You, followed instruction and still showing the same comment. Thank You for Your time anyways.

Comment: Please also try running this command `jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager` [Source](https://github.com/pandas-profiling/pandas-profiling/issues/244)

Comment: it can't find it as a command

Answer (score 0):

Marcelina, I had to use the following code to see the results since I was running it from a script or the command line (and it would just give me 1 blank row; how frustrating!):

```
import pandas_profiling,pandas,os
profileReport0=pandas_profiling.ProfileReport(pandas.read_csv(r'C:\Users\johndoe\Downloads\ipos.csv'))
file0=r'C:\Users\johndoe\Documents\profileReport0.html'
profileReport0.to_file(file0)
os.system(r'''start "" "'''+file0+'''"''')
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33680747)